# show all linq sql queries per request

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to display in my application a list of all executed linq to sql queries (with executed time would be nice) on every page for the current request (as a debug information).

Does anybody know how to do that or maybe someone has already build a class to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use SQL Profiler?

Comment: No because I want to display these informations on the live server (only for administrators), too. And I have no access to the sql server on the live server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataContext supports logging through the [Log property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx). Just attach a instance of a TextWriter and you're able to see all statements that are generated. Like this:

```
var dc = new DataContext();
dc.Log = Console.Out;
```

This will log all statements to the console window.

I can highly recommend [LINQ to SQL log to debug window, file, memory or multiple writers](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers) by Damien Guard. He different examples of logging to file, to the console and more.

Another option is to use [Linq 2 Sql profiler](http://l2sprof.com/) by Ayende. I have not used it myself but i use NHProf on a daily basis and i'm more than happy with it.

Comment: Great - that's exactly what I wanted to know! Thanks a lot!